# php read and parse streamed output, or alternately send blocks to file

Tags: php, bash, stream

The GOAL of this question is to find out how to parse streamed data from a process using PHP.  For example, I can run this command:

```
kubectl get pods -n rias -w -o json
```

from the CLI and it will continue to stream blocks of JSON.   In other words, the process never ends.

How would you read and parse the JSON blocks that come out of this using PHP?

As an alternate approach, if there were some way (perhaps using Linux) I could write the blocks to files in a folder with a timestamp, I could process and delete them with a running PHP script.  This would work but doesn't seem very efficient.  Thanks.

Comment: If there is one block per line then read a line and parse it

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using a bash script.  It's very rudimentary and there are things I want to do to make it more robust, but this does work:

```
stream_kubectl_watcher() {
    # Note: `pods` and `rias` should be arguments, perhaps -o type
    # to make this function flexible
    kubectl get pods -n rias -w -o json
}

parse_kubectl_watcher() {
    i=0
    buffer=""
    file=""
    while read -r line; do
        ((i++))
        if [[ $line == '{' && $buffer == '}' ]]; then
            echo "starting new input at $i .."
            filename="file$i"
            # send to file; could also send to an API etc
            echo "writing $filename"
            echo $file > $filename
            file=$line
        fi
        file="$file$line"
        buffer=$line
    done < <(stream_kubectl_watcher 2>&1)
}
```

Big items to note:

- this creates a file from each block but one could easily pipe the command to a PHP, Python or Go script as well
- I've joined `stdout` and `stderr` and have not tested what will happen
- there is an issue, the JSON lines are being trimmed on the left side and I think there is an `$IFS` variable I need to use to fix this.  However, as long as this doesn't cause parse errors in the JSON, it's a feature not a bug, as the stream will be a bit smaller - perhaps even a lot in some cases

Comment: If you need to do something like this then it means that the json objects are split across multiple lines?

Comment: From what I've seen, yes, the JSON objects are separated across newlines.  Even without that, the string `}{` (end one JSON block and start another) would never be valid in a _single_ JSON object - unless it was found in a quoted string.